# Regular Expression to retrieve password from connection string

Tags: c#, regex

How do I write a regular expression to retrieve password from connection string.

Connection string is like this:

```
USER ID=system;PASSWORD = ab;DATA ..
```

or

```
USER ID=system;PASSWORD=ab;DATA ...
```

or

```
USER ID=system;PASSWORD =ab;DATA...
```

or

```
USER ID=system;PASSWORD= ab;DATA ...
```

Tried the approach of using ConnectionStringBuilder. Works for SQL Server. But in case of Oracle it throws this exception:

```
Invalid length for connection option 'Data Source', maximum length is 128.
```

The Oracle Connection String:

```
USER ID=sa;PASSWORD=abc;DATA SOURCE="(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.1.1)(PORT = 8080))(CONNECT_DATA =(SERVER = DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME = Orcl)))"
```

Comment: So password never contains semicolon or spaces?

Comment: It may be easier to use the `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.aspx

Comment: Stackoverflow is not for `write me my code`

Comment: http://www.whathaveyoutried.com

Comment: SqlConnectionStringBuilder is certainly one way to go. But in that case I have to change the builder based on the database the query is being generated for. If it can be managed just with the use of regex, a one liner solves my problem.

Comment: @buffer_overflow: If the above is a SQL connection string as specified in MSDN then go with driis solution and save you some headache with regex.

Comment: @buffer_overflow: You would have to bother with all the special cases of escaping which is hard with regex.

Comment: @buffer_overflow, if your worry is that it's more code - then that is what functions are for :-)

Comment: `var password = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder("USER ID=system;PASSWORD =ab;").Password;` one liner :p

Answer (score 9):

Is there a requirement that you have to use a regular expression ? .NET has the functionality built in:

```
var sb = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder("USER ID=system;PASSWORD =ab;");
Console.WriteLine(sb.Password);
```

This is likely to be more robust than using a regular expression for that. The rules for the fields are rather comprehensive, and it is easy to make a Regex that will work for *most* connectionstrings, but will fail on some. See [the connection string rules](http://www.connectionstrings.com/Articles/Show/important-rules-for-connection-strings) for a list of the rules that must be embedded in such a Regex.

Answer (score 1):

Regex:

```
.*PASSWORD[ ]*=[ ]*([^;]+)
```

Comment: Semicolons are allowed in the password

Comment: So where is the stop of the password then. I don't know how semicolons are escaped in your connection string.

Comment: http://www.connectionstrings.com/Articles/Show/important-rules-for-connection-strings

Comment: can you use [[:blank:]]* in C# regexp? instead of .* or [ ]*

Comment: Using regex when the connection string contains escaping with ' makes it nearly impossible. So don't use regex at all for it.

Comment: is the string `;DATA ...` allowed in the password? or `PASSWORD=` allowed as an id?